# ID with special characters with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, character

I have a ID with special characters. I need to get the value of this input with JQUERY.

```
<input style="text-align:center; width:50px;"  type="text" onKeyPress="jq(this.id);" value="5" id="adhocGlobal_#@HELLO DAVID%VSOP1240%6X0.7LFIG">
    <script> 
    function jq(str) {
        var id = str.replace(/[%#;&,\.\+\@*~':"!\^\$\[\]\(\)=>|\/\\]/g, '\\\\$&');
        var value = $("#"+id).val();
        alert(value);
}
    </script>
```

I try with this, but i dont have response in the alert.
Help! please!

Comment: your desired id ??

Comment: i want the value contained in the input

Comment: what is str value then ?

Comment: `var id = str.replace()` .There was target with new id .If you need `new id ` input value are or` keypress` input value.

Comment: the id yes. but in jquery if you use the id with special characters it doesnt work. then I created jq  method what to write "\\" before each special character.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can use jQuery's escape sequence in a selector, `\\`, to escape special characters. However that won't work in this case as the `id` you have specified in the element is invalid as it contains spaces.

Due to that you will have to use the attribute selector in jQuery to retrieve it:

```js
var $el = $('[id="adhocGlobal_#@HELLO DAVID%VSOP1240%6X0.7LFIG"]');
console.log($el.val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input style="text-align: center; width: 50px;" type="text" onKeyPress="jq(this.id);" value="5" id="adhocGlobal_#@HELLO DAVID%VSOP1240%6X0.7LFIG">
```

A much better solution would be to fix the `id` of your elements before they are output in to the page to remove the spaces and special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Get the answer from fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamkarthik08/bpyr33be/3/)
 I have written in both javascript & jquery. There is an option fot trying // before every special character in ID, but that doesn't worked for me. So on the other way you can get the answer. Check & let me know.

```
$("#clickID").on('click', function(){
    getVal = $(document.getElementById('adhocGlobal_#@HELLO DAVID%VSOP1240%6X0.7LFIG')).val();
    console.log(getVal);
    alert(getVal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function jq(str) {
    var element = document.getElementById("adhocGlobal_#@HELLO DAVID%VSOP1240%6X0.7LFIG");

    var value = $(element).val();
    alert(value);
}
```